# Read KMZ with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kmz

How I can read the content in a KMZ (not KML) with JavaScript?

Comment: um.... so which is it? KML per your title, or KMZ per your question content?

Comment: Do you actually want to do something with the KML inside the KMZ (which is simply a ZIP file) with your JavaScript, or do you simply want to display the data in the KML inside the KMZ on a map?

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to see if it is possible to unzip the files. I would look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript) on using JavaScript. After that you will probably have a string of XML which you will need to convert to XML using the [DOM parser](http://www.pascarello.com/TestHTMLXMLfromServer.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use geoxml3.js with ZipFile.complete.js available at [KMZ](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fkmz)

```
     <script src="js/ZipFile.complete.js"></script>
     <script src="js/geoxmlv3.js"></script>

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapId), {
        zoom: 11,center: {lat: 0,lng: 0}
      });
      var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map
      });
      myParser.parse(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

geoxml3 now supports kmz files (in the [kmz](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fkmz) branch).