# Is there a client side JavaScript mimetype library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mime-types

I'm looking for a client side JavaScript mimetype library similar to [Python's mimetypes](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html), or the ['mime' Node module](https://github.com/bentomas/node-mime).

I have two related use cases in mind.  First is for validating the mimetype in an `<input type="file"/>` element.  The second is for validating a bunch of filenames that come reading the file entries of a ZIP file via [js-unzip](https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip) and [Cheeso's unzip utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript/2097303#2097303).

Comment: This resource looks helpful:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: It's the right direction.  Using the FileReader class works for the first use case when it's available (currently Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first target you can use list of [mime types by extention](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml) convert in to JSON compress with gz and then use with your script. It's the most simplest way to do this crossbrowser.

The second you can use bash-comands in node, untar archive to tmp and then get mime types of the each file. Parse result with js and check if it compares with you validation list

Comment: Yeah it seems there's nothing in a JS library, or convenient access to the browser's mimetype mapping, except maybe by playing tricks with the FileReader class.  As you suggested I ended up rolling my own for my specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

checkout [node-mime](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime) thay have a browser version