# Merge remote files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question. Suppose that I have 2 files on remote site.

- `http://example.com/path/to/file1.txt`
- `http://example.com/path/to/file2.txt`

Is it possible to be merged before letting the user download it?

**file1.txt**

```
This is the content in file1.txt
```

**file2.txt**

```
But this is the content in file2.txt
```

**merged_file.txt** (The file that the user will get)

```
This is the content in file1.txt
But this is the content in file2.txt
```

---

**Follow up questions**

- If possible: can it be merged if the remote files have `Content-Disposition: attachment` as a header?
- If impossible: can it be zipped together and let the user download a single file instead of multiple text files?

Comment: Use JavaScript / AJAX to asynchronously download both  the files, assemble them, then [do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016088/1790644) to allow the user to download it.

Comment: Yes, these are all possible.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Merging is of course possible. But how do you zip them in browser?

Comment: @bravemaster [How to Zip files using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8608724/215552)

Comment: @MattClark Thanks. I have a question (for clarity) at `download both the files`: does this means you have to save the files on the sever first?

Comment: @TacticalBacon No, it is not necesary, you do not need to save it into server or into local disk before, you download both files into client browser memory and generate the zip into a blob into client browser like MattClark and Heretic Monkey described, it's HTML5 amazing magic. It's like mega web does: it downloads (and decrypts) data before into memory and then a save dialog appears.

Comment: Also, about jszip, the answer that was removed because didn't even credit the comments: in that answer the user used the nodejs code, be very cautious about using an example for the client's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this to download the contents of each file, load them into an array, then act on the array when all the files are done downloading. It wil require s ome more logic to assemble the files and to make sure all the files are actually done downloading, but it is possible.

```
function dl(target, callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", target, true);
    xhr.send();
}

dl("file_a", onDone);
dl("file_b", onDone);

document.files = new Array();
function onDone(data) {

    document.files.push(data);
}
```

Then use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24898081/1790644) to download the files from the JS cache to the users desktop.

```
function download() {

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(document.files);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'in-line.txt';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```