# How to create a folder containing multiple images and download it as a zip file - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, zip, filesystems

I'm working on a React.js application, I have multiple html canvas that I can download individually as a png image. I look now for a way to wrap all these images in a folder (let's call it assets folder) and after that downloading this folder in zip format.

Here is my code:

```js
const download = (canvas, index)=>{
  var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = `img_${index}.png`;
  link.href = url;
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}

for(let k=1; k<=5; k++){
  //There is a bunch of code here that generates a new canva in each iteration. I don't include it to keep things simple!!!
  download(canvas.current, k)
{
```

Screenshot for downloaded image:

[image]

Comment: Maybe here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608724/how-to-zip-files-using-javascript ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for.