# How to modify the current code to read .docx file using HTML5 file api

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi

I am using the below code to read a Word document file. This code worked fine when I used it to read a text file

```
 $('#xfilex').live('change', function() {
 var file = document.getElementById('xfilex').files[0];
 if(file) {
           var reader;
           reader = new FileReader();
           reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
           reader.onload = loaded;
          }
 });
 function loaded(evt) {
                var fileString = evt.target.result;
                var str = fileString;
                alert(str);
 }
```

But this code is unable to read .docx/.doc file. Please help me correct the code.

Comment: What happens when you run this on a .doc file, what happens when you run it on a docx file? What errors do you get? What exactly do you mean by "read", which part is performing the document conversion here?

Comment: .doc is a proprietary file format, .docx is an compressed (IIRC) XML format. Both are not trivial to process using JavaScript alone. I would leave this up to a server to handle.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks you so much for clarifying on this. Actually I don't have any access on server everything we do is like play in DOM( client side ) manner using jQuery.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read a DOCX file, you need to unzip its content (which is a mix of folders, xml files, and resources like images).
Maybe you can have some clues in this post :
[Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)

I doubt you can read a DOC file because it's a binary (and closed) format.

Comment: The problem with DOC is just it is closed, you can read binary file with JavaScript.

Comment: This is a 5years old answer, is there another way to do this right now?