# Cannot read a zip file inside browser

Tags: javascript, zip

I am using below code to read a ZIP file at client side

```
 var Zfile = new Zipfile( $('#xfilex').val() );
 var file = Zfile.entries[0];
 // From Here file reading continues... I am giving this to say what I am trying to accomplish
 if(file)
 {
    var reader;
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = loaded;
 }
```

But I am unable to read the file... Please help me to find mistakes in the above code. It is pure JavaScript and taken the reference from [Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript) Question. I hope I can get help.

Comment: You cannot read files from local file system due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: Please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript

Comment: Where did you get the zipfile class from?