# Node: Downloading a zip through Request, Zip being corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the excellent [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library for downloading files in Node for a small command line tool I'm working on. Request works perfectly for pulling in a single file, no problems at all, but it's not working for ZIPs.

For example, I'm trying to download the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) archive, which is at the URL:

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip
```

The relevant part of the code is:

```js
var fileUrl = "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip";
var output = "bootstrap.zip";
request(fileUrl, function(err, resp, body) {
  if(err) throw err;
  fs.writeFile(output, body, function(err) {
    console.log("file written!");
  }
}
```

I've tried setting the encoding to "binary" too but no luck. The actual zip is ~74KB, but when downloaded through the above code it's ~134KB and on double clicking in Finder to extract it, I get the error:

> Unable to extract "bootstrap" into "nodetest" (Error 21 - Is a directory)

I get the feeling this is an encoding issue but not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with encoding. When you wait for the whole transfer to finish `body` is coerced to a string by default. You can tell `request` to give you a `Buffer` instead by setting the `encoding` option to `null`:

```
var fileUrl = "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip";
var output = "bootstrap.zip";
request({url: fileUrl, encoding: null}, function(err, resp, body) {
  if(err) throw err;
  fs.writeFile(output, body, function(err) {
    console.log("file written!");
  });
});
```

Another more elegant solution is to use `pipe()` to point the response to a file writable stream:

```
request('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bootstrap.zip'))
  .on('close', function () {
    console.log('File written!');
  });
```

A one liner always wins :)

`pipe()` returns the destination stream (the WriteStream in this case), so you can listen to its `close` event to get notified when the file was written.

Comment: Great, thank you! That first code blocked worked :) The second way is nicer, but I need a way to run a callback once the file is written, which is why I'd gone for the first option.

Comment: You can still get a callback when the file is written in the second option by listening to the `close` event on the WriteStream: 
`request(fileUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output)).on('close', function () {console.log('File written!');});`

Comment: That's much nicer! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @juandopazo Really great information! I have been hitting a brick wall for last two days and your code snippet solved the problem. If I may ask, is this documented somewhere? how did you come across this information?

Comment: It's in the `request` docs. It says "If null, the body is returned as a Buffer." https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: @juandopazo, Its working great. Currently file store in particular path. But I would like to download zip file with "save dialog box". So how its possible?

Comment: You can't do that with Nodejs, but you can write a command line script that takes an argument for the output location. Just google "nodejs create command line tool"

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Can't believe this only has 16 up votes! Couldn't find info on downloading through node anywhere.

Comment: `{encoding: null}` concludes 10 hours of debugging. Thanks, this need to rank up in google search

Comment: I was breaking my head over downloading an zip from presigned s3 url containing device farm reports as customer artifacts. {encoding: null} - This finally solved my problemd

Answer (score 3):

I was searching about a function which request a zip and extract it without create any file inside my server, here is my TypeScript function, it use [JSZIP module](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```js
let bufs : any = [];
let buf : Uint8Array;
request
    .get(url)
    .on('end', () => {
        buf = Buffer.concat(bufs);

        JSZip.loadAsync(buf).then((zip) => {
            // zip.files contains a list of file
            // chheck JSZip documentation
            // Example of getting a text file : zip.file("bla.txt").async("text").then....
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .on('data', (d) => {
        bufs.push(d);
    })
```