# Node.js http/fs returns a corrupted ZIP file

Tags: node.js, http, zip, fs

I've been trying to build an update system in my webapp to download and parse some data automatically from [this location](http://phmsa.dot.gov/staticfiles/PHMSA/DownloadableFiles/Pipeline/PHMSA_Pipeline_Safety_Flagged_Incidents.zip). When I access the site manually in my browser I have no problem downloading and opening the zip file there, but when I try this implementation (from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134/6909866)) I get a zero-KB file that circularly unzips into a `.cpgz` and back again:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.downloader = function(url, filePath, callback) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    var request = http.get(url, function(res) {
        res.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('downloaded!');
            file.close(callback);
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        fs.unlink(filePath);
        if (callback) callback(err.message);
    });
};
```

I don't have much experience working with streams or downloading files directly - does this particular site handle download requests abnormally? Is the `.cpgz` anomaly just because the write stream is creating an empty file?

Comment: Give this a try? You might need to adjust the encoding -
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029764/1427161

Comment: Thanks @doublesharp, that Request example works nicely - is there a way to change the response encoding when just using node's http?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? The encoding can be set per connection.