# How to download and write a jar file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, jar, request

So I'm working on a Minecraft launcher (because why not, good experience), and I'm stuck when it comes to downloading the libraries.

I have a valid jar URL [here](https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar). When you download it in the browser, it works fine. But, when you download it with Node.js, 7-zip gives this error when trying to open it:

```
An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.
```

I'm using a module called [snekfetch](https://github.com/devsnek/snekfetch), but I've also tried it with [request](https://github.com/request/request). Both items gave the same issue. Here's my current test code:

```
request.get('https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar').then(r => {
  fs.writeFileSync('./mything.jar', r.body);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong to download the jar file?

Okay, so now that I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029523/node-downloading-a-zip-through-request-zip-being-corrupted), I need to modify the question. I've gotten it to work using pipes, but I need inline-code because this is a for loop that's downloading (hence my usage of writeFileSync, and in my actual code I use await for the request). Is it even possible to download and write without piping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue with the snekfetch library. Switching to snekfetch v3 fixed it.

You can check out the status of the issue [here](https://github.com/devsnek/snekfetch/issues/42).