# Node.js Not able to convert x-zip-compressed to application/zip

Tags: node.js, zip, azure-blob-storage, mime-types, npm-request

Here is part of my code which is fetching a zip file uploaded to Azure blob, and sending it back to the caller.

The content-type returned by Azure is `application/x-zip-compressed`. However, I need to return `application/zip`. If I do not set the header in my code, it returns  `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. If I do set the header as in my code below, it returns `application/zip; charset=utf-8`. The result is even if the file gets downloaded, I am not able to open it with winzip.

My question is, how do I convert the file to `application/zip`?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
request.get("https://path-to-my-azure-storage-blob/"+ fileName, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error){
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  } else {
      console.log("Status Code: ", response.statusCode)
      console.log("Content-type: ", response.headers['content-type'])
      res = {
      "status": 200,
      "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip'
       },
      "body": body
    };
    res.end();
  }
});
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Why the downloaded blob/zip is 'corrupt' is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029764/1225266

So the solution is (which can be simplified even more if you'd like)

```
request.get("https:/....blob.core.windows.net/folder/some.zip", null)
    .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .on('response', function(response) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': response.headers['content-type'],
            'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=anotherfilename.zip',
            'Content-Length': response.headers['content-length']
        }); 
      })
    .on('data', (d) => {
        res.write(d);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        res.end()
    });
```

You can about how you can pipe the response from azure directly to the client here https://github.com/request/request#streaming