# How to store zip response in local file in expressjs + nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, zip, unzip

I working on some code, which makes a call to 3rd party service and receives application/zip content-type data in response now i want to save that response as zip file in local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

// using request module

```
 request(url)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filename.zip'))
      .on('close', function () {
        console.log('File written!');
      });
```

This might also be helpful: [Node: Downloading a zip through Request, Zip being corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029523/node-downloading-a-zip-through-request-zip-being-corrupted)