# zip file download using node and vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, zip, archive

I am using nodejs archive for creating my zip file. I need to download this zip file via axios.

this is my node js code.

```
let zipFile = fs.createWriteStream(zipFilePath);
    var archive = ar('zip');

    zipFile.on('close', () => {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });

    zipFile.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Data has been drained');
    });

    archive.on('warning', (err) => {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            console.log('worning');
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });

    archive.on('error', (err) => {
        throw err;
        res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
    });

    archive.on('finish', () => {
        console.log("zip file generate");
    });

    archive.pipe(zipFile);
    archive.pipe(res);

    res.on('close', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', archive.pointer());
    })
    archive.append(fs.createReadStream(englishFilePath), { name: englishFileName });
    archive.append(fs.createReadStream(spanishFilePath), { name: spanishFileName });
    archive.finalize();
```

this is my vuejs code for download the zip file

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.body]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.setAttribute('href', URL)
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", zipfileName);
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
```

now I am able to download a zip file, but it was corrupted.

Comment: Maybe use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029523/node-downloading-a-zip-through-request-zip-being-corrupted for reference?