# node.js, fetch a zip file and unzip it to ram

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I need help, how to fetch a zip file and unzip it to memory, or maybe write it to harddisk.

sample url

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = "http://www.caltrain.com/Assets/GTFS/caltrain/Caltrain-GTFS.zip"
var file = fs.createWriteStream("./file.zip");

http.get(url, (res) => {
    var test = res.pipe(file);
    console.log("it's finished")
    console.log(test)
})
```

I am not sure how the asycnc-api works, does createWriteStream wait for the whole buffer? and how to write it to disk?

// I find a better solution after hours of googling, [How to download and unzip a zip file in memory in NodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359485/how-to-download-and-unzip-a-zip-file-in-memory-in-nodejs)

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use for example [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip). Also useful to read about [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Comment: hi, i am confused as when the file has finished downloading, I keep getting an "write after end" error

Comment: are you trying to unzip it to ram or disk? you mentioned both

Comment: hi danilopopeye, either way is fine. The easier one to perform

Comment: well, you can tag it as duplicate, I am not that familiar with stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the mentioned packages: [request](https://github.com/request/request) & [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)

```
# download and save the file to filesystem
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.zip'))

# extract it to `output/path`
fs.createReadStream('file.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));
```

Or if you don't need the zip file, you can extract it directly from memory:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));
```

Comment: I am also trying to understand nodejs. The code uses async module but written as sync, I am having trouble with understanding the timing.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "the code uses async module but written as sync". my snippet didn't work?

Comment: I try your code,  unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' } create new folder , but folder is empty. I am assuming, it is because fs is still empty... does .pipe() accept callback  ??

Comment: the second alternative code works, but the first code does not work. anyway thanks