# Download zip with axios and unzip with adm-zip in memory (electron app)

Tags: node.js, axios, electron, adm-zip

I need to download a file with `axios` and unzip it in memory in an electron app.

I read in some SO threads ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359485/how-to-download-and-unzip-a-zip-file-in-memory-in-nodejs)), that `adm-zip` supports byte buffer constructor, but I can not see this in the docs. When I extract the content, it behaves like the array is empty, but it is not. It just does create a file and does not throw any errors I do not want to use `request`, as the api is marked deprecated. My code is this:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
   
const url = "http://update-service.test.w3champions.com/api/maps";
const body = await axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
const data = body.data;
const zip = new AdmZip(data);
zip.extractAllTo(to, true);
```

I feel super stupid, because I had it one time working and then changed something and now I do not seem to find the error again :/ I sadly did not commit the working state...

edit:
So, we figured it out: Electron does some weird stuff that returns an Array Buffer instead of a Buffer, that adm-zip would need. As I am lazy added the package `arraybuffer-to-buffer` and now the code works:

```
const arrayBufferToBuffer = window.require('arraybuffer-to-buffer');
const url = `${this.updateUrl}api/${fileName}?ptr=${this.isTest}`;
const body = await axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});

const buffer = arrayBufferToBuffer(body.data);
const zip = new AdmZip(buffer);
zip.extractAllTo(to, true);
```

Comment: For anyone reading this question looking for the answer, please look at the edit here. `arrayBufferToBuffer` is the same as `const buffer = Buffer.from(body.data);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the typeof data, maybe its not buffer.

Adm implementation: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/adm-zip.js

[image]

Comment: It is an array buffer, at least chrome tools say that.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwnufon8vilz1o3/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Hey, you are right, i just debugged into it and it takes the last else, which is an empty file. Somehow arraybuffer and buffer are not the same. Gonna investigate this.

Comment: If you want to copy my result? I think the answer is better to find, if it is together with the answer.

Answer (score 10):

It works the same with `axios`. The code below is a working example.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

const f = async () => {
    const url = 'http://update-service.test.w3champions.com/api/webui';
    const body = await axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });

    var zip = new AdmZip(body.data);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();

    // search for "index.html" which should be there
    for (var i = 0; i < zipEntries.length; i++) {
        console.log(zip.readAsText(zipEntries[i]));
    }

    // and to extract it into current working directory
    zip.extractAllTo('.', true);
};

f();
```

Comment: The zips contain some folders with files, I want to unzip. I updated the URL for another file to make it more clear.

Comment: The code above does just that. `zip.readAsText(zipEntries[i])` will return unzipped files as text. It works for your new url as well except that it contains binary data so it is not very helpful.

Comment: And i just copied your code and I do not see anything in the log. Also `extractAll` from `adm-zip` does not do anything. Dont know why this is so hard o.O

Comment: It does, you just need to wait because the file is large. So it takes time before it is downloaded.

Comment: Maybe i should add that this is an electron app, but this should not matter all to much. It also does not have anything to do with file rights, i can create text files from my app on the same location.

Comment: On what location? This is running in memory, not on a disk.

Comment: I am debugging it, when the get is done, I have the whole array in memory, but it does not get to console or the folder :/ also the webui zip is only a few kb and this also does not extract.

Comment: yes, but the `extractAll` goes to the disk. And as i said, the console log returns an empty string for me.

Comment: Even if it returns and empty response in console, you wouldn't see anything useful there because it is not text. So what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Try to copy paste the code that I have written now and wait till it finishes.

Comment: I am trying to tell you, that the index.html gets printed out as an empty string in the code you provided. And I dont know why :< I added my repo if you want to reproduce it

Comment: i copied it, the whole thing, the console stays empty

Comment: Here is screenshot if you do not believe me https://www.dropbox.com/s/pslkvrj5yo4zhpo/Capture.JPG?dl=0
I really do not get it, it looks like an exception is just swallowed or the array is empty.

Comment: I see. It has to be electron thing. Running your github code now, will update you if I figure something out.

Comment: I got it, the other answer pushed me in the right direction. I debugged into the adm files and saw, that it wanted a buffer, but axios delivers an array buffer. Must be an electron speciality xD I fixed it and will post the answer. Thanks for the help though!