# Unzip a file with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, zip

I have a phonegap application which will need to take a zip archive of a webpage, unzip it, and display the output.

I have been looking around for ways to zip/unzip with phonegap and have been coming up short. Since it's all Js it seems like [JsZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) might hold an answer but their [test suite](http://stuartk.com/jszip/test/) has nothing on unzipping.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

Edit for posterity: I DID ultimately get javascript unzipping working with [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) and a bunch of wrapper code. It worked fine but is quite processor intensive. Unzipping a 15mb zip file in chrome on a desktop took about 40 seconds. For anything where performance is a concern (most things), I would recommend stepping down a level and using a component directly from ios/android.

Comment: Hi George!! Did you finally get this to work?? Because it seems there's a plugin for this task (https://github.com/filmaj/Hydra/tree/master/ext/iOS/plugins/ZipUtil), but not documentation yet. So instead of figuring out how to use it, I'd go for this approach as long as it works in iOS

Comment: Curse you @GeorgeMauer! I was looking for how to actually doing it with the Obj-C since your JS way takes FOREVER and stumbled upon this post. (For those unaware (so, everyone), George and I are working on the same project, or I should say George dumped it off on me.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439837/unzip-plugin-for-phonegap-2-3-or-higher-in-android plz see the question

Comment: Very nice @AshishNautiyal I assume this preforms a lot better than all-javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this one: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Unzip-Example.htm

More info: [Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks dda. I'm pretty sure this will work with Phonegap but have you ever used it for that?

Answer (score 1):

cordova-plugin-zip worked for me.  It supports native unzipping for iOS and Android.
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript approach does not work you can always just write a Plugin.

Comment: Yes. Not production grade, but I wrote a quick app to test it.