# Load compressed text file into a String using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unzip files using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)

What should I do If I have a simple compressed text file (in a .zip/.rar/... file) and I want to read it into a String with JavaScript?

In other words if the content of my compressed test.txt file is "Hello world", then what should I do to copy this "Hello word" text into a String?

How to do this? 
Which compression format should I use (.zip/.rar/other)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did that compressed text file makes its way into your JavaScript?

Comment: You could load any document from JS via AJAX methods, but I don't know how to decompress it. e.g. `jQuery.ajax( { url: 'THE_FILE_NAME', complete: function( jqXHR, status ) { /* … */ } } );`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, AJAX was part of the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you succeeded in loading the compressed file to a javascript variable (through AJAX?), follow this similar question in order to unzip it:

[Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for this link! It was realy helpgul to understand the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but I have not enough reputation to upvote your post. Thank you for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

Try use zip.js: http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/

Example: http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/demos/demo2.html