# how to ZIP images using phonegap by using the URI

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to zip few images(5 images) captured using android phone camera via phonegap and to transfer the zip file to server(java).

Is it possible zip the images using there URI either by using the java script or using phonegap API ? or if it is only possible through native call, how can we call a native method with the parameters(URI) from the phonegap?

any links related to this will be this will be very helpfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

hi i think these links may help you.

[zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) this is a javascript zip  library.

or I found A ios plugin [link](https://github.com/filmaj/Hydra/tree/master/ext/iOS/plugins/ZipUtil)

or 
Stack over flow question [javascript zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)