# How can I unzip a compressed xml file from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, zip

On my site I show a huge numbered vehicle-paths. I get the coordinates via ajax, but sometimes its too slow because of the filesize. I want to compress it, its okay, but I can't uncompress it before I process the xml in javascript (with jQuery). Unfortunately I can't use php in the server side. Have somebody any idea?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks, I checked it, but it isn't cross-browser solution. But I need something like this.

Comment: Other solutions might be to send json (such as file path) with ajax to the server and have the server language unzip the file for you, and respond once its completed the task.

Comment: But I need to download a smaller size, not upload to compress.

Comment: You can upload files with ajax, and then run server-process on that uploaded file.

Comment: I have the data on the server. The server compress it for the client side. I download it with ajax. I just want to download a smaller file, I don't want to upload anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions already on Stackoverflow if you take a look at [Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript) (contains a answer with [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/)).  Here is a blog post about decompression with javascript cross-browser (includes IE) [here](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/read-load-files-from-zip-in-javascript/).

> Other solutions might be to send json (such as file path) with ajax to the server and have the server language unzip the file for you, and respond once its completed the task.

Not sure what server-side language you're using. But there  are plenty of resources

- PHP [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2495-PHP-Pack-and-unpack-files-packed-in-ZIP-archives.html)
- python [gzip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html)
- Java [How to decompress files from a ZIP file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/)
- ASP.NET [Unzip a rar/zip File Programmatically RSS](http://forums.asp.net/t/1428916.aspx)

> **Thanks, I checked it, but it isn't cross-browser solution.** But I need something like this. [kree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469962/kree)

I'd recommend using some server-side language to process your `zip` files because it would be the easiest `cross-browser` solution.

Comment: Thanks, I checked them. My problem with the zip.js is it isn't cross-browser. Unfortunately I have to work with IE7 too... And the post contain dead links.
I should solve this problem on the client-side, our server can send only zipped files. Although, I thing I will force the competents to change it.

Comment: Here is a blog post about decompression with javascript cross-browser (includes IE) http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/read-load-files-from-zip-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Compress it using [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) and it will be completely transparent to your JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I should use it, but I can't set the Apache settings. I don't have rights to do it :/

Comment: @kree — so do it at the code level when generating your XML, or *get* the rights to do it (or get someone who does have the rights to make the change).

Comment: Ok, but my task is find a solution in the client side... Not my idea :/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make this more transparent, like in PHP:

```
ob_start('ob_gz_handler');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

This will send the output using gzip compression and the browser will automatically decompress it for you.

Alternatively, the web server itself could take care of compressing the output generated by any server-side scripts.

Comment: Om... I didn't write we don't use php. We have an own thing... Therefore I need to do it in the client side :S

Comment: @kree the web server can do it too.