# Number of lines in xls file using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

A user select a xlsx file from a input file tag, I want to get the number of lines in the xlsx file without submitting the form. Is it possible with javascript? If yes then please assist for the same and if not then let me know the alternate method to do the same. The server side language is PHP.

Comment: Depending on the browser, if HTML5 File API is supported, you can directly parse the XLSX file and get the number of rows.  For example, http://niggler.github.io/js-xlsx/

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My previous answer was totally wrong, so I removed it in this edit.

As a general solution, xls files are some sort of zip files, so you need to unzip the file first. sheets and data are stored in XMl format in that file. then you have to find your correct XML file in that zip file, then parse it. This wouldn't be easy and I'm not sure if there are any libraries available. For unzipping, have a look at http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/demos/demo2.html, and there is also another question close to topic about openoffice's files here [Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzip-files-using-javascript)

Plus of course there is always a dummy way using ActiveXObject :)

Comment: Can be done through javascript.

Comment: I just put the link there, is there any problem doing in this way?

Comment: Let alone that info is almost a decade outdated. It is very possible to read file contents through the HTML5 File API. Now how to interpret a xls file is a different thing.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, edited again, please have a look if there is anything wrong

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy It's only XLSX files which are zipped XML files. XLS files are a binary data format.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in the xls matter, but this seems about right. ActiveXObject would probably have a way to do that, but only for IE and with security restriction (having to accept that annoying yellow bar `:P`).