# How to unzip file on javascript

Tags: javascript, file, extract, unzip, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on hybrid mobile app using html5/js. It has a function download zip file then unzip them. The download function is not problem but I don't know how to unzip file (using javascript).
Many people refer to [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) but it seems only reading zip file (not unzip/extract to new folder)

Very appreciate if someone could help me !!!

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files)

Comment: extract them to where? JS can't save any files in specific folders...

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal: I have look at your link but still not have solution

Comment: @dandavis: I'm working on hybrid mobile app. I can download zip file to local, so I think create/save any files is not problem

Comment: you can extract all the files in the zip to the _downloads_ folder, but you cannot save them to "to new folder", or any specific folder other than _downloads_

Comment: OK, I see, but how to extract them ?

Comment: For future readers: @dandavis is describing javascript running in a browser - the usual situation - and limitations on what it can do. thanh0812474 is describing *a hybrid mobile app*. This is built using web technologies, including javascript, but it *is* an "app" running in the mobile device's OS (e.g. on iPhone, an iOS app, downloaded from app store). As such, it *does* have access to local device capabilities, just like a native app does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at zip.js documentation and [demo page](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html). Also notice the use of JavaScript [filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) to read/write files and create temporary files.

If the zip file contains multiple entries, you could read the zip file entries and display a table of links to download each individual file as in the demo above.

If you look the source of the demo page, you see the following code (code pasted from Github demo page for zip.js) (I've added comments to explain):

```
function(obj) {
//Request fileSystemObject from JavaScript library for native support
var requestFileSystem = obj.webkitRequestFileSystem || obj.mozRequestFileSystem || obj.requestFileSystem;

function onerror(message) {
    alert(message);
}
//Create a data model to handle unzipping and downloading

var model = (function() {
    var URL = obj.webkitURL || obj.mozURL || obj.URL;

    return {
        getEntries : function(file, onend) {
            zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), function(zipReader) {
                zipReader.getEntries(onend);
            }, onerror);
        },
        getEntryFile : function(entry, creationMethod, onend, onprogress) {
            var writer, zipFileEntry;

            function getData() {
                entry.getData(writer, function(blob) {
                    var blobURL = creationMethod == "Blob" ? URL.createObjectURL(blob) : zipFileEntry.toURL();
                    onend(blobURL);
                }, onprogress);
            }
            //Write the entire file as a blob
            if (creationMethod == "Blob") {
                writer = new zip.BlobWriter();
                getData();
            } else {
                //Use the file writer to write the file clicked by user.
                createTempFile(function(fileEntry) {
                    zipFileEntry = fileEntry;
                    writer = new zip.FileWriter(zipFileEntry);
                    getData();
                });
            }
        }
    };
})();

(function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
    var unzipProgress = document.createElement("progress");
    var fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");
    var creationMethodInput = document.getElementById("creation-method-input");
    //The download function here gets called when the user clicks on the download link for each file.

    function download(entry, li, a) {
        model.getEntryFile(entry, creationMethodInput.value, function(blobURL) {
            var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            if (unzipProgress.parentNode)
                unzipProgress.parentNode.removeChild(unzipProgress);
            unzipProgress.value = 0;
            unzipProgress.max = 0;
            clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.href = blobURL;
            a.download = entry.filename;
            a.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        }, function(current, total) {
            unzipProgress.value = current;
            unzipProgress.max = total;
            li.appendChild(unzipProgress);
        });
    }

    if (typeof requestFileSystem == "undefined")
        creationMethodInput.options.length = 1;
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
        fileInput.disabled = true;
      //Create a list of anchor links to display to download files on the web page
        model.getEntries(fileInput.files[0], function(entries) {
            fileList.innerHTML = "";
            entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.textContent = entry.filename;
                a.href = "#";
         //Click event handler
                a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                    if (!a.download) {
                        download(entry, li, a);
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                }, false);
                li.appendChild(a);
                fileList.appendChild(li);
            });
        });
    }, false);
})();

})(this);
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I have tried this source before. but it still not match with my require. Note that I'm working on mobile and function download zip file then unzip them is run on background.

Comment: The first link is dead