# Unzip a folder with files as a content on Angularjs, client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big issue or I don't find how to get a solution to this .
I need to request $http.get and I get a zip file, into this zip file I have images that I need to use on my client side. 
I tried doing with different responseType="arraybuffer" and no solution.
My logic is: get the zip file, then maybe I create the folder into my client side and  reuse these images that come in that zipFile.
Someone know a logic and how to implement the solution?
Thanks a million.

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files

Comment: The Cheeso's answer looks great  but haha He never uploaded the link for the source .

Comment: [JSZIP](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) on Github could be relevent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into using JSZip (links for [API](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip.html) and [upgrade guide](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/upgrade_guide.html)) to download a zip and extract image files, and came up with the following proof of concept code (outside Angularjs):

#### getZIP using JSZIP

```
function getZip( url){  // returns a Promise for the zip
    var resolve, reject, req;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    req.onload = function() {
        var zip = new JSZip();  // ************
        resolve( zip.loadAsync(req.response));
    };
    req.onError = req.onAbort = function(){
        reject( new Error("GET from " + url + " failed"));
    }
    req.send();
    return new Promise( function(r,j) {resolve=r; reject=j;});
}
```

which returns a promise that fulfills with a zip object if successful, and

#### A test to download a zip, extract and display an image

```
window.onload=function(){
    getZip("./test.zip")
    .then( processZip)
    .catch( function( err){
        console.log("something went wrong: " + err);
    });
}
function processZip( zip){
    zip.file("test.png")
    .async("base64")
    .then( function( data){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        })
    .catch( function(err){ throw err;});
}
```

which requires a `test.zip` file containing `test.png` in the same folder as the test page.

---

Although the concept appears to be working, there may be limitations (RAM usage, size of image files, performance) and browser caching (without immediate expiry) may be another way of speeding up image access.

Comment: So far this is a solution, I didn't have issues with this solution yet.
I know is bad logic to get a zip file from a server and do the load in my client side, but for everyone with same issue, this is the good solution. 
Thanks a million

Comment: @AngelaPat. I just corrected  the `resolve` call in `getZip` to  use the promise returned from `.loadAsync` so file content errors can be caught. And you're welcome.