# Extract zip from input

Tags: javascript, zip, user-input, client-side, unzip

I have a website which is GBA emulator and allows people to upload their own .gba files, most of these files are zipped files and I would like it to extract the input so the .gba file is passed instead of the zip file. All done client-side.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? and what the issue is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files

Comment: @EricS All I need to do is extract the zip file in the input so the .gba is the one actually getting passed. I have looked into zip.js and jszip but I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: @Pingbeat Links outdated and I want it client side.

Comment: Javascript is always client-side....

Comment: + That its old does not mean it does not work

Comment: @Pingbeat Sorry, I want the file client side.

Comment: @Pingbeat the links are dead....