# Return multiple files from the Spring @PostMapping method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipart

I upload some files to my `PostMapping` endpoint, it accepts `@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files`.

My application performs some logic over them, and I would like to send those images back as blobs. Can I do it with Spring? I have no problem returning 1 file back using the `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` return type, by just using `Files.readAllBytes(myOnlyFile)`, but I'm not sure how to do so for many files. Perhaps I need to return `ResponseEntity<byte[][]>`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a clean way to do it _with HTTP_.

Comment: @chrylis, interesting, why wouldn't it be clean? Because of the problems on the client-side, trying to interpret this massive 2d byte array?

Comment: What if we return zip file?

Comment: @PatelRomil, will I have to unzip it on the client? Or does JS do it automatically?
My client gets the result from an async `POST` request to the Spring endpoint.

Comment: No, because there's no way in HTTP to express multiple downloads in a way that any client will understand. The closest is something like a no-compression ZIP file. Otherwise, send one file at a time.

Comment: thanks @chrylis, I think I'll try the ZIP file then!

Comment: Do you want to display those images immediately after posting/saving

Comment: @PatelRomil I think I'd like to show them as soon as they arrive.

Comment: I think you have to unzip it on a client to show them. you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095697/unzipping-files